# Can submissions be automatically entered into a contacts database?

Tags: cognito-forms

For Cognito Forms, is there a way that each submitted entry into my Cognito Form can be automatically uploaded onto a contacts database such as Realeflow?

This would be helpful instead of exporting from Excel and importing back into the other database.

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for Cognito Forms. You can post submitted entries in real time using JSON. This can be set up on the Form Settings section of the build page. A short description of how JSON works can be found in [our support](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/66/data-integration/webhooks). You can then use [Zapier](https://zapier.com/) to send the JSON information to other applications. We have created a [blog post](http://blog.cognitoapps.com/author/mhoop/) that walks users though this process linking your form to a Trello board. I have also had success using Zapier to send submitted entry information over to MailChimp in real time.